# Zxing QR Code Reader without Bar Code Scanner

Tags: java, android, zxing, reader

I'm a newbie in Android world. 
I want to integrate the Zxing QR Code Reader (only QR Code, not BarCode) in my project, without installing the BarCode Scanner.
When I open my app, I want the scanner to open automatically.
I have read several solutions, but have never been able to apply them. Maybe because I use Android Studio, and the steps to integrate libs etc, are different.
I need all steps to do what I want.

I hope you. =)

Comment: You can try and use this as an alternative, [zbar](https://github.com/ZBar/ZBar/tree/master/android), you have to add the libs manually to your project and add `compile files('libs/zbar.jar')
` to your build.gradle. Also, add the CameraPreview class to your project, check the example how the calls are made in the MainActivity

Comment: @AhmedAbidi Thank you. I will try. :)